# Python Pandas - Retrieve row with timestamp locator and offset

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as follow:

[image]

If i want to retrieve a row at a certain timestamp no , problem, I do (for instance) : `price_data.loc['2005-03-11 13:00:00']`

However how do I do to retrieve the row that is below (for instance here 13:30 ?)

I would be looking for a solution such as `price_data.loc['2005-03-11 13:00:00']+1`. (Obviously doesn't work).

Currently I do `price_data.loc['2005-03-11 13:00:00'+pd.Timedelta(minutes=30)]` but my data has sometimes gaps so i am looking for an integer index based solution somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will work

```
df.ix[  df.index.get_loc('2005-03-11 13:00:00')+1]
```

Can't test because you have posted an image instead of code or text. As pointed out by Ken, this assumes that your df is in sorted order.

Comment: If this method is used, the dataframe must be sorted by date first.